# Find word/pattern/string in txt/xml-file and add incremental number

Tags: python, xml, regex, perl, increment

I'm using Textwrangler who falls short when it comes to adding numbers to replacements.
I have an xml-file with several strings containg the words:

```
generatoritem id="Outline Text"
```

I need to add an incrementing number at the end of each substitution, like so:

```
generatoritem id="Outline Text1"
```

So I need to replace 'Outline Text' with 'Outline Text' and an incrementing number.

I found an answer on a similar question and tried to type in this in textwrangler and hit Check Syntax:

```
perl -ple 's/"Outline Text"/$n++/e' /path/of/file.xml
```

Plenty of errors.. So I need to be explained this nice one liner. Or perhaps get a new one or a Python script?

Comment: `perl -h` explains the command line switches.

Answer (score 0):

-p makes perl read your file(s) one line at a time, and for each line it will execute the script and then emit the line as modified by your script. Note that there is an implicit use of a variable called $_ - it is used as the variable holding the line being read, it's also the default target for s/// and it's the default source for the print after each line.

You won't need the -l (the l in the middle of -ple) for the task you describe, so I won't bother going into it. Remove it.

The final flag -e (the e at the end of -ple) introduces your 'script' from the command line itself - ie allowing a quick and small use of perl without a source file.

Onto the guts of your script: it is wrong for the purpose you describe, and as an attempt it's also a bit unsafe.

If you want to change "Outline text" into something else, your current script replaces ALL of it with $n - which is not what you describe you want. A simple way to do exactly what you ask for is

```
s/(id="Outline text)(")/$1 . $n++ . $2/eg;
```

This matches the exact text you want, and notice that I'm also matching id= for extra certainty in case OTHER parts of your file contains "Outline text" - don't laugh, it can happen!

By putting ( ) around parts of the pattern, those bits are saved in variables known as $1, $2 etc. I am then using these in the replacement part. The . operator glues the pieces together, giving your result.

The /e at the end of the s/// means that the replacement is treated as a Perl expression, not just a plain replacement string. I've also added g which makes it match more than once on a line - you may have more than one interesting id= on a line in the input file, so be ready for it.

One final point. You seem to suggest you want to start numbering from 1, so replace $n++ with ++$n. For my suggested change, the variable $n will start as empty (effectively zero) it will be incremented to 1 (and 2, and 3 and ......) and THEN it's value will be used.

Comment: Thank you. I got it kind of working in the end. I'm using Textwrangler, and running the script from there does not work. Not even "Run in Terminal" but pasting the code directly in to Terminal produced the needed result, however inside the terminal and not on the file. I also needed to ad " ' " around your suggested code and also an extra "/" in front of /path/to/file.xml, like so: `perl -pe 's/(id="Outline Text)(")/$1 . ++$n . $2/eg;' //path/to/file.xml`

Comment: Ok. It's because I dont ask perl to write to the file(?) using -w. I changed the beginning to `perl -i -w -pe '`, thus getting the file changed instantly. So the simplest sollution (so far) is to drag and drop `perl -i -w -pe 's/(id="Outline Text)(")/$1 . ++$n . $2/eg;' /` in to the Terminal and then drag and drop in the sourcefile producing the `/path/to/file.xml`and hit enter. Maybe I should mention that I'm using Mac (OSX Mavericks)

Comment: Even though I can make this work somehow with perl, I find it not so straight forward (yet). Is there an increment function i Python? Ah, maybe in a way: [link](http://forums.udacity.com/questions/9902/isnt-there-any-increment-decrement-operator-in-python-like-or-)